# сервер на Raspberry Pi 4 для тг бота

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, сервер, raspberry-pi

Всем доброго времени дня. Интересует следующий вопрос: имеется RPi4 и несколько завершенных тг ботов. Возможно ли (и если да, то как (желательно подробно, новичок в этом деле)) использовать RPi4 как сервер для них. Более дня искал информацию по поводу этого в интернете, однако поиски не увенчались успехом

Comment: По идее, можно, но хз, что будет с производительностью.
А так, нужно поставить операционку и запустить бота, в инете должна быть инфа (Можешь у gpt спросить, он расскажет)

Comment: это зависит от установленной ОС и языка/фреймворка, на котором написан бот